# function() isn't reacting on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

to bring it to the point: my function isn't telling me anything when i submit the form. The url changes, but it seems like the function isnt fired. Please help!

```
<div id="contact_form">  
<form name="contact" action="">  
  <fieldset>  
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
    <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required.</label>  

    <label for="email" id="email_label">Return Email</label>  
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
    <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">This field is required.</label>  

    <label for="phone" id="phone_label">Return Phone</label>  
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
    <label class="error" for="phone" id="phone_error">This field is required.</label>  

    <br />  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />  
  </fieldset>  
</form>  
</div>  
<script>
    $(function() {  
  $('.error').hide();  
  $(".button").click(function() {  
    // validate and process form here  

    $('.error').hide();  
      var name = $("input#name").val();  
        if (name == "") {  
      $("label#name_error").show();  
      $("input#name").focus();  
      return false;  
    }  
        var email = $("input#email").val();  
        if (email == "") {  
      $("label#email_error").show();  
      $("input#email").focus();  
      return false;  
    }  
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();  
        if (phone == "") {  
      $("label#phone_error").show();  
      $("input#phone").focus();  
      return false;  
    }  

  });  
});  
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: Searched it already on google but didn't found a good result.

Comment: Uhmm... Like... Where's that function?

Comment: I cannot see any PHP in here!?

Comment: What function? The validation seems to be working fine, but once the form is submitted the javascript doesn't do anything, so what are you expecting ?

Comment: Starts at "<script> $(funktion() {" :/

Comment: Register the handler for the `submit` event of the form instead of the `click`event of the button. `$("form").on("submit", function() { ... })`

Comment: Why isnt it doing anything then?

Comment: What is it supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

First, add the event parameter to the button click handler, like this:

```
$(".button").click(function(e)){
```

Then also change

```
return false;
```

To

```
e.preventDefault();
```

EDIT:

This code works for me. When you click the button with fields empty, form is not submitted and it shows the error text next to the first field. By the way, there is no php involved here, just html and jquery. Are you loading jquery in your page?

```
<div id="contact_form">  
<form name="contact" action="">  
  <fieldset>  
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
    <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required.</label>  

    <label for="email" id="email_label">Return Email</label>  
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
    <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">This field is required.</label>  

    <label for="phone" id="phone_label">Return Phone</label>  
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
    <label class="error" for="phone" id="phone_error">This field is required.</label>  

    <br />  
   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />  
  </fieldset>  
</form>  
</div>  
<script>
$(function() {  
  $('.error').hide();  
  $(".button").click(function(e) {  
  // validate and process form here  

  $('.error').hide();  
    var name = $("input#name").val();  
    if (name == "") {  
      $("label#name_error").show();  
      $("input#name").focus();  
      e.preventDefault();  
      return;
   }  
    var email = $("input#email").val();  
    if (email == "") {  
  $("label#email_error").show();  
  $("input#email").focus();
  e.preventDefault();  
  return;
}  
    var phone = $("input#phone").val();  
    if (phone == "") {  
  $("label#phone_error").show();  
  $("input#phone").focus();
  e.preventDefault();  
  return;  
}  

});  
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Tried it, nothing changed :/

Comment: My server supports jQuery, but this isnt working for me :C I think Iam doing something completely wrong. The "this field is required" message is appearing by just loading the page and isn't disappearing when i fill in my email and click on send :/

Comment: Quote: _"My server supports jQuery"_.  ~ The server has absolutely nothing to do with _client-side_ code.

Comment: Well, "the client" supports it too :)

Answer (score 0):

Use it:

```
$('form[name="contact"]').on('submit', function() {

    $('.error').hide();  
    var name = $("input#name").val();  

    if (name.length == 0) {  
      $("label#name_error").show();  
      $("input#name").focus();  
      return false;  
    }  

    var email = $("input#email").val();  
    if (email.length == 0) {  
      $("label#email_error").show();  
      $("input#email").focus();  
      return false;  
    }  

    var phone = $("input#phone").val();  
    if (phone.length == 0) {  
      $("label#phone_error").show();  
      $("input#phone").focus();  
      return false;  
    } 

    return true; 
});
```

Comment: He's using jQuery... so **why** put `onSubmit` inline?  Just use `$('form[name="contact"]').on('submit', function() { ....`

Comment: You don't _need_ to post multiple answers... it's ok to have _one_ and edit it as needed.

Comment: This does not work for me :/ The "this field is required" errors are staying at its location no matter what i do (resend the form with filled patterns / etc) :/